# OCaml special characters formatting?

Tags: ocaml

I have the following ocaml code:

```
let rec c_write =                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  "printf(\" %d \");\n"
```

On calling this function in the interpreter, I expect to get the output 
printf("%d"); followed by a new line, but instead I get

printf(\" %d \");\n

How can I get my expected output when I'm calling the function without using any other I/O functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `let rec c_write = "printf(\" %d \");\n"` is not a function. It is a value of type `string` which is bound to a variable named `c_write`. So you're not using any I/O functions in your code.

When entered in the interactive toplevel, this value is printed by the interpreter evaluation loop for user convenience. The same as when a Python interpreter will print for you the value that you've just entered.

The representation, chosen by the OCaml toplevel interpreter, in general, has nothing to do with the representation which is used to store a value in a file or to print it. Moreover, in OCaml, there is no canonical representations.

If you want to write a function that prints a C printf statement then this is how it will look like in OCaml

```
let print_printf () = 
  print_endline {|printf("%d");|}
```

In the example above, I've used `{||}` to denote a sting literal instead of more common `""`, since in this literal there is no need to escape special characters and they are interpreted literally (i.e., the don't have any special meaning).

You can achieve the same result using the regular `""` quotes for denoting it

```
let print_printf () = 
  print_endline "printf(\"%d\");"
```

Here is an example of the toplevel interaction using these definitions:

```
# let print_printf () = 
  print_endline {|printf("%d");|};;
val print_printf : unit -> unit = <fun>

# print_printf ();;
printf("%d");
- : unit = ()

# let print_printf () = 
  print_endline "printf(\"%d\");";;
val print_printf : unit -> unit = <fun>

# print_printf ();;
printf("%d");
- : unit = ()
```

If you will put this code in a file, compile, and execute and redirect into a C file it will be a well-formed C file (modulo the absence of the function body).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are somehow using the toplevel printer for printing, and that you somehow needs a very specific format, you need to install a custom printer.
The following would work:

```
# #install_printer Format.pp_print_string;;
# " This \" is not escaped " ;;
- : string =  This " is not escaped
```

However, it seems very likely that this is not really the problem that you are trying to solve.